# AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]

Tags: gulp

I have gulp file that is having issues with latest update to gulp 4 I am getting assertion errors (**AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task function must be specified**) and it seems (from googling) to have to do with how tasks are defined, but not sure if this is the case here and what needs to change.
Node: node -v
v14.16.0

CLI version: 2.3.0
Local version: 4.0.2

NPM: 6.14.11
Here is the code

````
// ### CSS processing pipeline
// Example
// ```
// gulp.src(cssFiles)
//   .pipe(cssTasks('main.css')
//   .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist + 'styles'))
// ```
var cssTasks = function(filename) {
  return lazypipe()
    .pipe(function() {
      return gulpif(!enabled.failStyleTask, plumber());
    })
    .pipe(function() {
      return gulpif(enabled.maps, sourcemaps.init());
    })
    .pipe(function() {
      return gulpif('*.less', less());
    })
    .pipe(function() {
      return gulpif('*.scss', sass({
        outputStyle: 'nested', // libsass doesn't support expanded yet
        precision: 10,
        includePaths: ['.'],
        errLogToConsole: !enabled.failStyleTask
      }));
    })
    .pipe(concat, filename)
    .pipe(autoprefixer, {
      browsers: [
        'last 2 versions',
        'android 4',
        'opera 12'
      ]
    })
    .pipe(cssNano, {
      safe: true
    })
    .pipe(function() {
      return gulpif(enabled.rev, rev());
    })
    .pipe(function() {
      return gulpif(enabled.maps, sourcemaps.write('.', {
        sourceRoot: 'assets/styles/'
      }));
    })();
};

// ### JS processing pipeline
// Example
// ```
// gulp.src(jsFiles)
//   .pipe(jsTasks('main.js')
//   .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist + 'scripts'))
// ```
var jsTasks = function(filename) {
  return lazypipe()
    .pipe(function() {
      return gulpif(enabled.maps, sourcemaps.init());
    })
    .pipe(concat, filename)
    .pipe(uglify, {
      compress: {
        'drop_debugger': enabled.stripJSDebug
      }
    })
    .pipe(function() {
      return gulpif(enabled.rev, rev());
    })
    .pipe(function() {
      return gulpif(enabled.maps, sourcemaps.write('.', {
        sourceRoot: 'assets/scripts/'
      }));
    })();
};

// ### Write to rev manifest
// If there are any revved files then write them to the rev manifest.
// See https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-rev
var writeToManifest = function(directory) {
  return lazypipe()
    .pipe(gulp.dest, path.dist + directory)
    .pipe(browserSync.stream, {match: '**/*.{js,css}'})
    .pipe(rev.manifest, revManifest, {
      base: path.dist,
      merge: true
    })
    .pipe(gulp.dest, path.dist)();
};

// ## Gulp tasks
// Run `gulp -T` for a task summary

// ### Styles
// `gulp styles` - Compiles, combines, and optimizes Bower CSS and project CSS.
// By default this task will only log a warning if a precompiler error is
// raised. If the `--production` flag is set: this task will fail outright.
gulp.task('styles', ['wiredep'], function() {
  var merged = merge();
  manifest.forEachDependency('css', function(dep) {
    var cssTasksInstance = cssTasks(dep.name);
    if (!enabled.failStyleTask) {
      cssTasksInstance.on('error', function(err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        this.emit('end');
      });
    }
    merged.add(gulp.src(dep.globs, {base: 'styles'})
      .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: onError}))
      .pipe(cssTasksInstance));
  });
  return merged
    .pipe(writeToManifest('styles'));
});

// ### Scripts
// `gulp scripts` - Runs JSHint then compiles, combines, and optimizes Bower JS
// and project JS.
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  var merged = merge();
  manifest.forEachDependency('js', function(dep) {
    merged.add(
      gulp.src(dep.globs, {base: 'scripts'})
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: onError}))
        .pipe(jsTasks(dep.name))
    );
  });
  return merged
    .pipe(writeToManifest('scripts'));
});

// ### Fonts
// `gulp fonts` - Grabs all the fonts and outputs them in a flattened directory
// structure. See: https://github.com/armed/gulp-flatten
gulp.task('fonts', function() {
  return gulp.src(globs.fonts)
    //.pipe(flatten())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist + 'fonts'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

// ### Images
// `gulp images` - Run lossless compression on all the images.
gulp.task('images', function() {
  return gulp.src(globs.images)
    .pipe(imagemin([
      imagemin.jpegtran({progressive: true}),
      imagemin.gifsicle({interlaced: true}),
      imagemin.svgo({plugins: [
        {removeUnknownsAndDefaults: false},
        {cleanupIDs: false}
      ]})
    ]))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist + 'images'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

// ### JSHint
// `gulp jshint` - Lints configuration JSON and project JS.
gulp.task('jshint', function() {
  return gulp.src([
    'bower.json', 'gulpfile.js'
  ].concat(project.js))
    .pipe(jshint())
    .pipe(jshint.reporter('jshint-stylish'))
    .pipe(gulpif(enabled.failJSHint, jshint.reporter('fail')));
});

// ### Clean
// `gulp clean` - Deletes the build folder entirely.
gulp.task('clean', require('del').bind(null, [path.dist]));

// ### Watch
// `gulp watch` - Use BrowserSync to proxy your dev server and synchronize code
// changes across devices. Specify the hostname of your dev server at
// `manifest.config.devUrl`. When a modification is made to an asset, run the
// build step for that asset and inject the changes into the page.
// See: http://www.browsersync.io
gulp.task('watch', function() {
  browserSync.init({
    files: ['{lib,templates}/**/*.php', '*.php'],
    proxy: config.devUrl,
    snippetOptions: {
      whitelist: ['/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php'],
      blacklist: ['/wp-admin/**']
    }
  });
  gulp.watch([path.source + 'styles/**/*'], ['styles']);
  gulp.watch([path.source + 'scripts/**/*'], ['scripts']);
  gulp.watch([path.source + 'fonts/**/*'], ['fonts']);
  gulp.watch([path.source + 'images/**/*'], ['images']);
  gulp.watch(['bower.json', 'assets/manifest.json'], ['build']);
});

// ### Build
// `gulp build` - Run all the build tasks but don't clean up beforehand.
// Generally you should be running `gulp` instead of `gulp build`.
gulp.task('build', function(callback) {
  runSequence('styles',
              'scripts',
              ['fonts', 'images'],
              callback);
});

// ### Wiredep
// `gulp wiredep` - Automatically inject Less and Sass Bower dependencies. See
// https://github.com/taptapship/wiredep
gulp.task('wiredep', function() {
  var wiredep = require('wiredep').stream;
  return gulp.src(project.css)
    .pipe(wiredep())
    .pipe(changed(path.source + 'styles', {
      hasChanged: changed.compareSha1Digest
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.source + 'styles'));
});
````

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there are a few things wrong with your code.

`gulp.task('styles', ['wiredep'], function() {`

for example should be

`gulp.task('styles', gulp.series('wiredep', function() {`  etc.

`gulp.task` only takes three arguments.  You may have more places in your code like this.

---

`gulp.watch([path.source + 'styles/**/*'], ['styles']);` might actually be fine but lets be careful and make it a little more future-proof:

`gulp.watch([path.source + 'styles/**/*'], gulp.series('styles'));`

Etc.  change all of these in your `watch` task.

---

With `gulp.series` and `gulp.parallel` you no longer need something like `runSequence`.  So replace

```js
gulp.task('build', function(callback) {
  runSequence('styles',
              'scripts',
              ['fonts', 'images'],
              callback);
});
```

with

```js
gulp.task('build', gulp.series(
  'styles',
  'scripts',
  gulp.parallel('fonts', 'images')
  // callback);  // see below
);

Make these changes and you'll see if you need the `callback` in the `build` task - if you get a message about signaling async completion.

-----------

And you may have to move your `wiredep` task before your `styles` task.  Since you are using `gulp.task` rather than functions to create your tasks, you cannot refer to a task that hasn't been created yet.  That wouldn't be an issue if you used all named functions to create each task.
```

Comment: Mark, that works, thank you!!!! one last question. Getting one error: "TypeError: gulp.start is not a function on"

Comment: `gulp.start` is not supported in gulp v4.  You don't have it in this code, typically it can be replaced with `gulp.series`.